# There are drivers for my CPU?

Tags: drivers, intel

I have bad performance on my games, I have the drivers for mi graphics card, but i dont know if the drivers of my intel core i5 9300 are right

`inxi -G`

`Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] driver: i915`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Is your kernel up to date?

Comment: @matigo Is the 21.10

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lspci`?

Comment: @cocomac its a lot of text, but I think that this line is for the CPU ```00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake H] (rev 07)```

Comment: Not sure what "my games" are, but generally, UHD 630 is not for "my games". For better performance, you need a gaming GPU.

Comment: you should not expect the intel cofeelake GT2 grapicks with the UHD 630 driver to run any gpu intensive games,you need a better grapics card for the games to function properly,please give more details about your setup like GB of ram.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are not any drivers you need to install for your CPU.

Your CPU is supported at the kernel level.